# Create a bold font in R with bquote and variable

Tags: r, variables, expression

I have been trying to use bquote in R with variable substitution. Everything works but I am failing in trying to make the font bold. So basically I want to create a map and have the map Lat/Long labels in a bold font. Here is what I am doing:

```
stlat = 0
endlat = 40
stlon = 30
endlon = 100
latints = seq(stlat,endlat,10)
lonints = seq(stlon,endlon,10)
latlabs = sapply(latints,function(x) bquote(bold(.(x))*degree ~ bold(N)))
lonlabs = sapply(lonints,function(x) bquote(bold(.(x))*degree ~ bold(E)))
```

But the actual lat/long numbers still appear in the regular font and not in bold. Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do they have to be numeric at this point? If you do `sapply(latints,function(x) bquote(bold(.(as.character(x)))*degree ~ bold(N)))` it appears bolded

Comment: Wow wonderful yep that worked. I have been scratching my head behind this for so long. Thanks a lot!!